# Template not loading Spring MVC - JSF project

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc

Im new to Spring/JSF and trying to create a sample project..

My first page is to create a page with header, content and footer section using JSF template

The page is a static page and currently does not use any bean, so my faces-config and application-context file empty...For some reason the template is not loading ,

Here are my files,

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.tutorialspoint.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>ecomstore</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>ecomstore Maven Webapp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>ecomstore</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>     
</project>
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>


</beans>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config version="1.2"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

common.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
   <h:head></h:head>
      <h2>#{title}</h2>
     <h:body>
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:green; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="header" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/header.xhtml" >
               <ui:param name="defaultHeader" value="Default Header" />
            </ui:include>
         </ui:insert> 
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:black; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="content" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/contents.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>    
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div style="border-width:2px; border-color:red; border-style:solid;">
         <ui:insert name="footer" >
            <ui:include src="/templates/footer.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
      </div>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

contents.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>Default Content</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

footer.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>Default Footer</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

header.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <body>
      <ui:composition> 
         <h1>#{defaultHeader}</h1>
      </ui:composition> 
   </body>
</html>
```

home.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:body>
      <ui:composition template="templates/common.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="title" value="Home" />
         <ui:define name="content">             
            <br/><br/>
            hi
             <h:link value="Page 1" outcome="page1" />
             <h:link value="Page 2" outcome="page2" />          
            <br/><br/>
         </ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

I see the "Hi" message being displayed but the templates are not getting loaded...

Comment: Spring + JSF is understandable if one is just using a barebones JSP/Servlet container like Tomcat which doesn't offer Java EE standard EJB/JPA/CDI out the box, but Spring MVC + JSF? They're competiting frameworks and not intented/designed to run together. I don't do Spring/MVC, but aren't you carelessly overgeneralizing Spring DI as Spring MVC?

Comment: This is a basic page but my idea is to implement Spring + JSF (DI) in my other pages..

Comment: Yes, I know. But you literally said that you're using Spring MVC while that would make no utter sense in combination with JSF. As far as I see in your pom.xml and web.xml, you're actually using Spring DI, not Spring MVC. You should revise your question accordingly to avoid red herrings.

Comment: I implemented this logic based on http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/integrating-spring-and-jsf/..This project asis worked fine..Not sure why you think that pom.xml and web.xml does not implement a Spring MVC

Comment: Huh? Where does that tutorial say that it's using Spring MVC? Have you *read* it? As I guessed, that tutorial is just showing how to get started with Spring (DI/IoC) + JSF (1.2). No word about Spring MVC expect of a "related" link to a completely different tutorial not about JSF.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now..what you mean...Can you recommend any book that integrates Spring MVC & JSF..

Comment: Why do you keep asking for that? Are you trolling or so? It makes **no sense** to use Spring MVC and JSF together. They are competiting frameworks. It's like as asking how to use JSP and PHP or ASP together in one webapp. Spring DI/IoC (recognizable by that `application-context.xml` mess) is however compatible with JSF and often used to supplant Java EE standard CDI/EJB which is not out the box available in barebones servletcontainers like Tomcat/Jetty. You should choose between Spring MVC **or** JSF. Spring DI can in turn be used on both to manage beans and business services.

Comment: By the way, based on [your previous questions on the subject JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1050619+[jsf]) I'm afraid that you've a severe learning problem. I strongly recommend to take a pause and eat the elephant called "JSF" with one bite at a time. Buy a decent book on JSF 2.0. Do not read a tutorial which mixes JSF with a different framework before you get the full grasp on the elephant "JSF". Do not read an ancient tutorial which handles JSF 1.x with JSP. Since end of 2009, JSF 2.0 + Facelets has become the standard.

Comment: I got confused after integrating Spring(DI/IOC) & JSF....I was not able to differentiate between Spring(DI/IOC) and Spring MVC..After this discussion, its much clear..Thanks for enlightenment.